# Separate dock icons for separate spaces

Tags: dock

Is it possible for the dock to only display the running apps of the space that is currently being used and not all of the open ones?. In Linux that feature exists and I really miss it, it's called something like "isolate desktops" if I remember correctly. Couldn't find it in the settings and google search didn't give me anything.

Edit: I am on OS Mojave.